# Python typing for immutable collections: `Final[Set[T]]` vs `FrozenSet[T]`

Tags: python, typing

`frozenset` has existed in Python for a long time. `FrozenSet` is the corresponding type annotation in the `typing` module.

[PEP 591](https://peps.python.org/pep-0591) additionally added a `Final` type annotation for declaring non-reassignable variables.

Should we use `FrozenSet[T]` and/or `Final[Set[T]]`?

---

The same "immutable collection vs final mutable collection" question could be asked for:

- [`immutabledict[K, V]`](https://pypi.org/project/immutabledict/) vs `Final[Dict[K, V]]`
- `Sequence[T]` vs `Final[List[T]]`

Answer (score 2):

Immutable types and `Final` achieve different purposes.

- Immutable collection types like `Tuple` and `FrozenSet` and `immutabledict` represent values that cannot be mutated. These types do not define mutating methods like `tuple.append` or `frozenset.add`.
- `Final` prevents variable reassignment. If a variable `x` is marked as `Final`, it cannot be reassigned to a different value (via `x = ...`), but no restrictions are made about the value of `x` itself – `x` itself can potentially be mutated.

If we're striving for maximum type safety with Python type checkers, using `Final` in addition to immutable types makes sense, to prevent both mutation and reassignment. This seems usually desirable for global constant values (values like `math.pi`).

Comment: This is correct. I'll further note that you can annotate your set using `typing.AbstractSet`. This is an immutable set collection type, similar to how `typing.Sequence` gives you an immutable list like type.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I didn't realize that `AbstractSet` is immutable, that make sense - will use instead of `FrozenSet` in the future.